# How i can use CGAffineTransform for correct drag and drop

Tags: swift, animation, uipangesturerecognizer

I want to do drag and drop for UITextView via UIPanGestureRecognizer with auto aligning on center of the screen. For the first drag it works good, but if i try to do it again my drag start with init point of the UITextView. I don't know how to fix it.

First Drag

[image]

Second Drag

[image]

```
@objc func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: nil)

    switch gesture.state {
    case .changed:
        dragingText.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation.x, y: translation.y)

    case .ended:

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {

            self.dragingText.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: translation.y)

        }, completion: nil)
    default:
        ()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved a problem

```
 @objc func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = gesture.translation(in: nil)

    switch gesture.state {
    case .changed:

        dragingText.center = CGPoint(x: dragingText.center.x + translation.x, y: dragingText.center.y + translation.y )
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: nil)

    case .ended:

        let isInside = isInsideDragableAres()

        if isInside.0 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.dragingText.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: self.dragingText.center.y + translation.y )
            }, completion: nil)
        }
        else{
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.4, initialSpringVelocity: 0.7, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
                self.dragingText.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x, y: isInside.1! )
            }, completion: nil)
        }

    default:
        ()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CGAffine Transform is not necessary for your task. Try:

case .changed:
textview.center = CGPoint(x: textview.x + translation.x,
                y: textview.y + translation.y )

Comment: With this line, after a little bit dragging the textView go away from the screen

Comment: Try getting rid of the case .ended statement?

Comment: I can't do this, because when user stop dragging, i start animation to center the textView on the screen by current Y position.